# How to quartely a GDP series On

Tags: r, data.table

I m starting work with R now, and I m having troubles on quartely a GDP data.

The command that I am using is:

```
library("data.table")
pib<- read.csv("PIB.csv", header = TRUE, sep=";", dec=",")
setDT(pib)
pib
attach(pib)
aggregate(pib, by= PIB.mensal, frequency=4, FUN='sum')
```

My data is the following :

```
    datareferencia| GDP.month

 1:     01/01/2010| 288.980,20

 2:     01/02/2010| 285.738,70

 3:     01/03/2010| 311.677,40

 4:     01/04/2010| 307.106,60

 5:     01/05/2010| 316.005,10

 6:     01/06/2010| 321.032,90

 7:     01/07/2010| 332.472,50

 8:     01/08/2010| 334.225,30

 9:     01/09/2010| 331.237,00

10:     01/10/2010| 344.965,70

11:     01/11/2010| 356.675,00

12:     01/12/2010| 355.730,60

13:     01/01/2011| 333.330,90

14:     01/02/2011| 335.118,40

15:     01/03/2011| 348.084,20

16:     01/04/2011| 349.255,90

17:     01/05/2011| 366.411,50

18:     01/06/2011| 371.046,10

19:     01/07/2011| 373.334,50

20:     01/08/2011| 377.005,90

21:     01/09/2011| 361.993,50

22:     01/10/2011| 378.843,40

23:     01/11/2011| 389.948,20

24:     01/12/2011| 392.009,40
```

Can someone help me? I need to quattely both years 2010 and 2011!

Comment: How to quartely a GDP series On R ***

Comment: What do you mean by "quattley". May be just have small sample of data and show what do you want as the output.

Comment: I want to share the  data in four parts per year..  the first quartely of 2010 would be the GDP sum of the months january, february, march and april.. the second quartely of 2010 would be the GDP sum of months may, june, july and august... so on !   I need do this for the years 2010 and 2011.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `by` command of `data.table` to do this. A variable for year and "quatley" is all you need.

Reading in your data:

```
pib <- data.table(datareferencia = c("01/01/2010", "01/02/2010", "01/03/2010",
                                     "01/04/2010", "01/05/2010", "01/06/2010",
                                     "01/07/2010", "01/08/2010", "01/09/2010",
                                     "01/10/2010", "01/11/2010", "01/12/2010",
                                     "01/01/2011", "01/02/2011", "01/03/2011",
                                     "01/04/2011", "01/05/2011", "01/06/2011",
                                     "01/07/2011", "01/08/2011", "01/09/2011",
                                     "01/10/2011", "01/11/2011", "01/12/2011") ,
                  GDP.month = c( 288980.20, 285738.70, 311677.40,
                                 307106.60, 316005.10, 321032.90,
                                 332472.50, 334225.30, 331237.00,
                                 344965.70, 356675.00, 355730.60,
                                 333330.90, 335118.40, 348084.20,
                                 349255.90, 366411.50, 371046.10,
                                 373334.50, 377005.90, 361993.50,
                                 378843.40, 389948.20, 392009.40))
```

Adjust your date if it is not already done:

```
pib[, datareferencia := as.IDate(datareferencia, format = "%d/%m/%Y")]
```

With the `year` function from `data.table` you get ... well the year.
For the "quatley" I use the modulo function `%/%` with the month and a little adjustment, so that the result is 1 to 3 and not 0 to 2.

```
pib[, quatley := ((month(datareferencia)-1) %/% 4) + 1 ]
pib[, year := year(datareferencia)]
```

At last you can calculate the `sum` by `year` and `quatley`:

```
pib[, sum.quatley:= sum(GDP.month), by = c("quatley", "year")]
```

The result:

```
unique(pib[, list(quatley, year, sum.quatley)])
   quatley year sum.quatley
1:       1 2010     1193503
2:       2 2010     1303736
3:       3 2010     1388608
4:       1 2011     1365789
5:       2 2011     1487798
6:       3 2011     1522795
```

Comment: @JacobGepp


It didn't work here... the results is giving me the same GDP to all years and all quarters.. 

the results is:

quatley year sum.quatley

 1:       1 2010    39095304

 2:       2 2010    39095304

 3:       3 2010    39095304

 4:       1 2011    39095304

Comment: numeric..

I resolve this question using the following command:

pib[, PIB.mensal := as.numeric(gsub("[.,]", "", PIB.mensal)) / 100]

ls(pib)
str(pib)

funcao <- sum
ini <- "01/03/2010"

ini <- which(pib[, datareferencia] == ini)
l <- (1 : ceiling(nrow(pib) / 3) * 3) - (3 - ini)
l <- l[l <= ceiling(nrow(pib))]
l <- l[(l - 2) > 0] # Tirando trimestres incompletos
pib[l, PIB.mensal := unlist(lapply(l, function(i) funcao(pib[i - (2 : 0), PIB.mensal])))]
pib <- pib[l, ]